# Perl: Using Loop or Map/Grep?

Tags: perl, dictionary, grep, readdir

I'm writing a program to step through a directory tree (Yes, I know about File::Find, but I'm writing a replacement).

In my program, I'm doing a `readdir` on a whole directory and placing it in a list. I need to do two things:

1. Remove `.` and `..` from the list
2. Prepend the current directory name on each file.

I can do this with a loop, or I can use `map` and `grep`:

```
# Map and Grep

my @dir_stack = readdir $dir_fh;;
@dir_stack = grep { !/^\.{1,2}$/ } @dir_stack;
@dir_stack = reverse map { "$cwd/$_" } @dir_stack;
push @stack, @dir_stack;

# Read Loop

opendir $dir_fh, $cwd;
my @dir_stack;
foreach my $file (readdir $dir_fh) {
    next if $file =~ /^\.{1,2}$/;   #Skip "." and ".."
    unshift @dir_stack, "$cwd/$file";
}
push @stack, @dir_stack;
```

What about combining `grep` and `map`?

```
 opendir $dir_fh, $cwd;
 my @dir_stack = readdir $dir_fh;;
 @dir_stack = grep { !/^\.{1,2}$/ && {$_ = "$cwd/$_"} } @dir_stack;
 push @stack, reverse @dir_stack;
```

I want my code to be *readable* next week when I look at it and try to figure out what's going on. I also need my code to be efficient.

Comment: Is there a subtle reason for your double semicolons after `readdir`?

Comment: @TimN - Nope. I didn't catch it in my code.

Comment: [Another one?](http://p3rl.org/Path::Class::Rule#SEE-ALSO) Have mercy, for CPAN’s sake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modifying `$_` in grep? yuck! And what's with using an anon hash constructor?

```
@dir_stack = grep { !/^\.{1,2}$/ && {$_ = "$cwd/$_"} } @dir_stack;
```

should be

```
@dir_stack = map { /^\.\.?\z/ ? () : "$cwd/$_" } @dir_stack;
```

But I personally find using both map and grep more readable than combining them.

```
push @stack,
   reverse
    map "$cwd/$_",
     grep !/^\.\.?\z/,
      readdir $dh;
```

The need for `reverse` is rather odd, and it's much more visible here than hiding as a `unshift`, so that's another bonus.

Comment: +1: If not combining `map` and `grep` leads to performance problems, the directory is way, way too big.

Comment: I combined `map` and `grep` in a single `grep` for performance reasons. I've noticed that `map` and `grep` aren't that much more efficient than a loop. If I used them both, wouldn't a loop would be more efficient? Reverse/unshift isn't needed, but I want to keep the files in order as they are with `find`. Does combining all of these commands into a single super command more efficient than doing it line-by-line? Can they operate in parallel, or doe `grep` have to complete and return a list before `map` can do anything. If it's the latter, I'd prefer to list each line.

Comment: @David W., `readdir` does return the same order as `find`. You're reversing it twice: Once using `reverse` and then once using a stack. To preserve order, drop the `reverse`, and use a *queue* instead of a stack (push+shift instead of push+pop).

Comment: @David W., To paraphrase your question, "does removing three array assignments make it more efficient than doing it line-by-line", and the answer is yes. Not only is it more readable, not doing three assignments is faster than doing three assignments.

Comment: @David W., What makes you think than combining into that grep is faster than combining into that map?

Answer (score 2):

To make your code more readable, you just need to include one more line:

```
# exclude '.' and '..', and prepend dir name to each elem in @dir_stack
```

:-)

Comment: Comments shouldn't repeat the code, but state the goal.  "# Full path names of directory contents." is a *much* better comment.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may want [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) instead. Though I believe it will exclude all files beginning with `.` (i.e. hidden files), not just `.` and `..`. And of course, you can't have spaces in the path.

```
my @stack = glob "$dir_fh/*";
```

It will return as long a paths as you feed it.

Comment: I'm running v5.10 and `glob "*"` includes both `.`, `..` and hidden files and directories.

Comment: @TLP : The `$]` in the codepad paste is confusing. What does `$^V` give you?

Comment: @Zaid `version  `  which is not a character recognized by my browser. Not sure why that happens, but it's on codepad's end. So I used `$]` instead.